# ERROR : The relation doesn't exist (create table)

Tags: postgresql, ddl

I'm new on Postgresql (9.2) and I have a problem creating tables in a specified schema

When I create the same tables in the public schema it works fine but in my "test" schema it doesn't

```
--> ERREUR:  la relation « intervention_site » n'existe pas
--> ERROR: the relation « intervention_site » does not exist.
```

Maybe a right problem?

Comment: Show us full command - right now it doesn't make much sense, as table creation doesn't require any other table to exist.

Comment: Read this: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/ddl-schemas.html and see if it's an issue with search_path etc.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that the `test` schema is not in your search path.

You can change this by a number of methods.  you can change it temporarily or for the session with:

```
SET search_path=test;
```

When you are done, you can reset:

```
RESET search_path;
```

If you want to set this as the default for a given db user:

```
ALTER USER foo SET search_path=test;
```

Or to reset:

```
ALTER USER foo RESET search_path;
```

You can also alter databases in this way.

If you want to continue to be able to check for tables in public, use a comma separated list:

```
SET search_path=test,public;
```